# how can I filter dups from this list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following list of objects:

```
{
DomainName="my-corp-1",
GroupName="group-x",
Desription="my group x"
}

{
DomainName="my-corp-2",
GroupName="group-x",
Desription="my group x - follow up with admin"
}

{
DomainName = "my-corp-1",
GroupName="group-y",
Description="my group y"
}
```

If an object with the same GroupName exists in both domains then I should keep the object which exists in my-corp-1 and filter out the object with the same GroupName associated with my-corp-2.

For example, in the list of objects above, the second object in the list should be filtered out b/c the GroupName already exists for group-x in the first object.

What would be a clean way to implement this filtering routine in C#?

Comment: What have you tried to do that is not working?

Comment: Look at Linq Distinct

Answer (score 0):

What's clean tends to be a personal preference :)

I would probably group them by the GroupName, and then act from there. Keeping data until the absolute last step is usually preferable.

```
// Get an IEnumerable of IGrouping with GroupName as key
var objectsGroupedByGroupName = myDomainList.GroupBy(d => d.GroupName);

// Recklessly throw away data and select only the first object in each grouping per GroupName
var listOfDomainsWithUniqueGroupNames = objectsGroupedByGroupName.Select(x => x.First());
```

If you just want it more clean, you can of course combine them:

```
var myUniqueDomainsFromGroupName = myDomainList
    .GroupBy(d => d.GroupName) // Group domains by their group name
    .Select(x => x.First())  // Select the first entry for each group
    //.ToList() if you want a list back
    ;
```